# Can't run CRON PDOException Magento 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, exception

I'm using the **Magento Module AOE Scheduler** do control my crowns. All the jobs in the cron are running without errors when I run them manually but the cron never runs. When I check the cron directly via SSH it is throwing the following exception and errors:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'last_seen' in 'where clause'' in /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>
> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'last_seen' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT main_table.* FROM cron_schedule AS main_table WHERE (status = 'running') AND (last_seen < '2018-04-16 22:03:00')' in /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> 1 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> 2 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> 3 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
>
> 4 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
>
> 5 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
>
> 6 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
>
> 7 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521):
>   Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
>
> 8 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
>
> 9 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/ProcessManager.php(98):
>   Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
>
> 10 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/ProcessManager.php(144):
>   Aoe_Scheduler_Model_ProcessManager->checkRunningJobs()
>
> 11 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(61):
>   Aoe_Scheduler_Model_ProcessManager->watchdog()
>
> 12 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358):
>   Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatchAlways(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> 13 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatchAlways', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> 14 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/app/Mage.php(448):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('always', Array)
>
> 15 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/shell/scheduler.php(519): Mage::dispatchEvent('always', Array)
>   16 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
>   17 /home/119209.cloudwaysapps.com/jnzzusxetf/public_html/shell/scheduler.php(545): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
>   18 {main}
>   How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't execute the Aoe_Scheduler setup scripts, so the column in the database has not been created.

A Google search for your error + "aoe scheduler" returns the module's official github: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues/173

Comment: That's true, but i have installled the module with composer, no just via FTP. I created the column but the module down work as should. I will try to reinstall. In my searches i didnt find that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As `simonthesorcerer` said you need to run the setup scripts, this can be done with [Magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)

SSH onto the server, download magerun and use the command `n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run`